# Is there a Hermitian conjugate function for numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

There is a hermitian conjugate function for `numpy.matrix` object, which is `numpy.matrix.H`. However `numpy.matrix` is not recommended and such a method does not seem to exist for `numpy.ndarray`. Currently I'm using `numpy.ndarray.T.conj()` which works, but is there a shorter method for hermitian conjugate ?

Comment: Your subject line is misleading.  You DO know how to perform this operation, and compactly.  What you are seeking is a shortcut, one that adds little, if any computational value.  Look at the docs/code for `.H`.  All it does is `self.transpose().conjugate()` or just `self.transpose()`.

Comment: It is not misleading. I did not ask how to do it, but whether it existed for the specific `numpy.ndarray` class, because I expected it to exist but could not find it. It turns out that `numpy.ndarray.H` does **not** exist, and that's a satisfying answer for my question. You seem to be the only one to have been misled here

Comment: In any case the lists of attributes/methods for `np.matrix`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy.matrix, and for and `ndarray`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#array-attributes are accurrate, without any any hidden or forgotten ones.

Comment: Possibly `.H` was added to `np.matrix` because MATLAB has a `x'` and `x.'` for Hermitian and transpose.  This subclass was written years ago to make `numpy` more appealing to wayward MATLAB users.